# How to activate a self-hosted global Dart package with public dependencies?

Tags: dart, dart-pub, pub.dev

I have this package hosted on JetBrains Space:

```yaml
name: my_package
description: Description of my package
version: 1.0.0
homepage: https://www.mywebsite.com

publish_to: https://dart.pkg.jetbrains.space/path/to/my/repo

environment:
  sdk: ^3.1.0

dependencies:
  glob: ^2.1.2
```

I did the following:

- `dart pub token add https://dart.pkg.jetbrains.space/path/to/my/repo` and entered the secret
- `export PUB_HOSTED_URL=https://dart.pkg.jetbrains.space/path/to/my/repo` (override the default pub.dev repo)
- `dart pub global activate my_package` and it fails with:

```
Because every version of my_package depends on glob any which doesn't exist (could not find package glob at
  https://dart.pkg.jetbrains.space/path/to/my/repo/), my_package is forbidden.
So, because pub global activate depends on my_package any, version solving failed.
```

Of course it doesn't find `glob` because I have configured `dart pub` to fetch on my private repo. But what I'm supposed to do? Re-hosting `glob` and all its transient dependencies? There must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://dart.dev/tools/pub/custom-package-repositories#retrieving-dependencies-from-a-custom-package-repository, I believe that you can explicitly specify the host URL for each dependent package with the `hosted:` property.  For example:

```dart
dependencies:
  glob:
    hosted: https://pub.dev
    version: ^2.1.2
```

Alternatively, if your private package doesn't need to be a dependency for anything else, you could consider instead publishing it to a private Git repository and avoid using `PUB_HOSTED_URL` entirely.